# Some MyBatis SQL Connection remain Open

Tags: java, mybatis

I have a chron job running that uses Java 8 /MyBatis. The job runs as expected but many of the database connections are remain even though `session.close()` is being called. Is there a way I can monitor connections still in place a set a timeout on htem How do I make sure all connections are closed at the end of a job?

Here is the code that sets up the session and closes the connection:

```
 protected ConnectionDao setupDao() {
        Environment env = new Environment("tempo", new JdbcTransactionFactory(), getDataSource());
        Configuration config = new Configuration(env);
        config.addMapper(ConnectionDao.class);
        SqlSessionFactory factory = new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(config);
        session = factory.openSession();

        return session.getMapper(ConnectionDao.class);
    }

    protected void closeSession() {

        if (session != null) {
            try {
                session.close();
                logger.info("mybatis session closed cleanly");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                session.close();
                logger.info("mybatis session closed within an exception");
                logger.severe(e.getMessage());
            }
        }

    }

//Datasource

 protected DataSource getDataSource() {

        return DataSourceBuilder.create()
                .driverClassName(driver)
                .url(url)
                .username(user)
                .password(password)
                .build();

    }
```

Comment: There is probably a connection pool behind the datasource - this is expected behavior with a connection pool. How is the datasource being built?

Comment: Thanks @JeffButler - I've added the datasource creation to the OP for clarity. It appears that a connection pool isn't being defined. Should there be?

Comment: There is probably a connection pool in play. Spring Boot's DataSourceBuilder will use a connection pool if there is an implementation on the classpath (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/jdbc/DataSourceBuilder.html). In general, connection pools are a good thing and will vastly improve the performance of your application. Most connection pools have configuration properties that will define their size, connection timeout, etc. I recommend that you continue to use the connection pool - but configure it properly for your needs.